# Unable to load map_view on fullscreen on Flutter

Tags: google-maps, android-activity, flutter

I have an issue when I try to load a google map in fullscreen.
I have followed all the docs in pub.dartland.org for map_view :

in my AndroidManifest.xml I had :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Also added :

```
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="your_api_key"/>
 <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

Of course with the apiKey changed, and also :

```
<activity android:name="com.apptreesoftware.mapview.MapActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>
```

I also add the kotlin dependencies in build.graddle.
So now I can see the staticUri map on the device, great, but when I tap on this map to get it in fullscreen, the app crash with this error :

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 4373): Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime( 4373): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 4373): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.apptreesoftware.mapview.MapActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

E/AndroidRuntime( 4373): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime( 4373): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
E/AndroidRuntime( 4373): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
```

I tried by adding :

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"/>
```

But same issue, maybe someone have an idea ?

EDIT :
Here is my AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

    <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="my-app"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

            <meta-data
                android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                android:value="true" />
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
            <!-- <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/> -->
            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>       
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.apptreesoftware.mapview.MapActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Could you paste your androidmanifest.xml file ?

Comment: Post has been edited with the AndroidManifest.xml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, you need to move the google maps meta-data outside your `activity` tag , like this:

```
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            package="com.example.myapp">

            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>

            <application
                android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
                android:label="my-app"
                android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">


                    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="XXXXXXXXXXXXXX"/>
                    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/> 

                <activity
                    android:name=".MainActivity"
                    android:launchMode="singleTop"
                    android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
                    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density"
                    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
                    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

                    <meta-data
                        android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame"
                        android:value="true" />
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>
                <activity android:name="com.apptreesoftware.mapview.MapActivity" android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"/>

            </application>
        </manifest>
```

You can find more information here:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/meta-data-element

In summary, the metadata is related to the parent component, so in this case you need that metadata for all of the app, not just for one activity :).

Comment: Nice it works now, not sure to understand well why, but I should probably learn more about android developpement instead of going straight in flutter dev. Thanks !

Comment: I added more description to my answer :)